# ng-repeat with function to create new objects and avoid [$rootScope:infdig]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

[plunker preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/GPPyW5ekVqxg9vYYSlR3?p=preview) 
I have the main array with information about users. 
Each item (user) has 'data' array:

```
{
  name: 'Linda',
  data: [
    {
      value: 3
    },
    {
      value: 6
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to print the main array like this:

- Linda - 3
- Linda - 6

**UPDATED**: And I can change names in inputs. See version 2.

---

So I use ng-repeat with function which returns new object. And I get known error: **[$rootScope:infdig]**

To avoid this error I use [google groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/IEIQok-YkpU/iDw32-YRr3QJ) approach: 'change' filter and 'linker' factory.
(I wanted to use $$hashKey approach. But I didn't understand how to do it)

To get this error, open my code and remove 'change' filter in HTML.

**Question**: maybe do you know easier solution to print array? Thanks.
And If I will sort before print?

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
    {
      name: 'Linda',
      data: [
        {
          value: 3
        },
        {
          value: 6
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'John',
      data: [
        {
          value: 2
        },
        {
          value: 11
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  $scope.getUsersData = function(){
    var output = [];
    $scope.users.forEach(function(user){
      if ('data' in user) {
        user.data.forEach(function(userData){
          output.push({name: user.name, value: userData.value});
        });
      }
    });
    return output;
  };
});

// From https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/IEIQok-YkpU/iDw32-YRr3QJ
app.filter('change', function(linker) {
   return function(items) {
      var collection = items.map(function (item) {
        return item;
      });

      return linker(collection, 'some-key');
    };
});

app.factory('linker', function () {
  var links = {};
  return function (arr, key) {
    var link = links[key] || [];

    arr.forEach(function (newItem, index) {
      var oldItem = link[index];
      if (!angular.equals(oldItem, newItem))
        link[index] = newItem;
    });

    link.length = arr.length;

    return links[key] = link;
  }
})
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in users = getUsersData() | change track by $index">{{user.name}} - {{user.value}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
     <input ng-model="user.name"/>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: you can't use function in ngRepeat like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[plunker version 3](http://plnkr.co/edit/GPPyW5ekVqxg9vYYSlR3?p=preview)
I need to change *user name* inside input fields. So I think the easy and fast solution for me is use $watch

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
    {
      name: 'Linda',
      data: [
        {
          value: 3
        },
        {
          value: 6
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'John',
      data: [
        {
          value: 2
        },
        {
          value: 11
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.$watch(function(){
    return JSON.stringify($scope.users);
  }, function(){
    $scope.usersData = $scope.prepareUsersForPrint($scope.users);
  })

  $scope.prepareUsersForPrint = function(arr){
    var output = [];
    arr.forEach(function(user){
      if ('data' in user) {
        user.data.forEach(function(userData){
          output.push({name: user.name, value: userData.value});
        });
      }
    });
    return output;
  };
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in usersData track by $index">{{user.name}} - {{user.value}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
      <input ng-model="user.name"/>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't add a `$$hashKey` property to the objects in your array if you use `track by`. `$$hashKey` is the default property added by angular to keep tracking your changes in given **array**.
Use `ng-repeat` without `track by` to make use of **hashKey**

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like this.** without filter or nested ng-repeat

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var users = [{
    name: 'Linda',
    data: [{
      value: 3
    }, {
      value: 6
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    data: [{
      value: 2
    }, {
      value: 11
    }]
  }];

  $scope.getUsersData = function() {
    var output = [];
    users.forEach(function(user, ind) {
      if ('data' in user) {
        user.data.forEach(function(userData, ind) {
          output.push({
            name: user.name,
            value: userData.value
          });
        });
      }
    });
    return output;
  };
  $scope.userFetchedData = $scope.getUsersData(); // here is the magic

});




app.factory('linker', function() {
  var links = {};
  return function(arr, key) {
    var link = links[key] || [];

    arr.forEach(function(newItem, index) {
      var oldItem = link[index];
      if (!angular.equals(oldItem, newItem))
        link[index] = newItem;
    });

    link.length = arr.length;

    return links[key] = link;
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in userFetchedData track by $index">{{user.name}} - {{user.value}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```